# Color Scale over List

Tags: javascript, css

I have an unordered list that may contain up to 10 items.  Within each `li` is a numeric value.  I want the first number to be green, the last number to be yellow, and each number between to be scaled between the two accordingly.

I'm curious if this can be done with css3 alone, or if I'd need JavaScript to calculate the interim and apply it (I could probably work out a JS solution on my own, but I don't know it's worth it at the moment)

Essentially I'd replace the `number-good` classes (e.g., green) with the scaled value instead.

```
<ul id="dash-top-customer-list" class="tb-list">
    <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="8">
        <span class="tb-list-name">OEM2</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$208,057</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="13">
        <span class="tb-list-name">Potential3</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$206,988</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="9">
        <span class="tb-list-name">REP1</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$191,029</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="14">
        <span class="tb-list-name">Potential4</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$187,609</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="15">
        <span class="tb-list-name">Potential5</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$183,372</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(this is hardly a must-have, and the question is more a curiosity than anything - I was surprised I couldn't find a pertinent question already asked (or my google-fu is really in the can today))

Comment: _"Within each li is a numeric value."_ Which value are you referring to? `208,057`?

Comment: _each number between to be scaled between the two accordingly_ - what does this even mean? Scaled according to what criteria? Should each element be '11.11% of the difference between smallest and largest' larger than the previous? (10 elements, thus 9 intervals)

Comment: @enhzflep Most likely OP means that the numbers should be gradiently colored, from green to yellow.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is changing, and you want to recalculate the values, you might want to consider JavaScript. Especially if you want to order the list. This sounds a lot like what d3.js helps with, so it might be worthwhile to have a look into that as it allows you to create color scales.

Another option in JS would be to set up an array of colors and then have a switch statement that assigns colors to the DOM elements.

If it isn't dynamic, then you can simply set up 10 color / classes in your stylesheet and give the DOM elements the class that you want each element to have.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 colorizeListItems( document.getElementById('dash-top-customer-list'), -60, 120 );
}

function colorizeListItems(targetUl, hueRange, hueMin)
{
 var liNodeList = targetUl.getElementsByTagName('li');
 var liArray = [].slice.call(liNodeList);

 var valueArray = liArray.map( function(liElem) { return liElem.querySelectorAll('span')[1].textContent.replace(/,*\$*/g, ''); } );
 var largest,smallest,difference;
 largest = smallest = valueArray[0];
 valueArray.forEach( function(curVal) {if (curVal < smallest) smallest = curVal; if (curVal > largest) largest = curVal;} );
 difference = largest - smallest;

 liArray.forEach( function(elem, index)
      {
      var curScaledVal = (valueArray[index] - smallest) / difference;
      var curHue = (curScaledVal * hueRange) + hueMin;
      var curStr = "hsl(" + curHue.toFixed(0) + ", 100%, 50%);";
      elem.setAttribute('style', 'background: ' + curStr);
      }
     );
}
```

```html
 <ul id="dash-top-customer-list" class="tb-list">
  <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="8">
   <span class="tb-list-name">OEM2</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$8,000,000</span>
  </li>
  <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="8">
   <span class="tb-list-name">OEM2</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$5,000,000</span>
  </li>
  <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="8">
   <span class="tb-list-name">OEM2</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$6,000,000</span>
  </li>
  <li class="tb-list-item" data-dym-id="8">
   <span class="tb-list-name">OEM2</span><span class="tb-list-value number-good">$7,000,000</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```